# Blazor login path for multiple authentication schemes (AAD and AB2C)

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I want to use Azure AD and Azure B2C in one application. I registered both authentication schemes which works fine.

Now I want to allow the user to decide which scheme should be used by clicking a "login with AD" or "login with B2C" button. Clicking on one of the buttons should redirect the user to the correct login.

I'm able to do this for AD by using the link `MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn`. To do this, it's necessary to use `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI()`

So, how do I get a link like above for B2C?

Here is my code:

```
        public static void AddAzureADAuthenticationApp(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection configuration)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    configuration.Bind(options);
                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        await AuthorizationHelper.ValidateAADAppToken(context);
                    };
                })
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi().AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddRequirements(new AzureADAuthorizationRequirement()).Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI(); 


            services.AddAuthorization(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddRequirements(new AzureADAuthorizationRequirement()).Build();
                config.AddPolicy(Constants.PolicyInternalUsers, policy);
            });

        }

        public static void AddAzureB2CAuthenticationApp(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection configuration, bool RequireAccountNum = false)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    configuration.Bind(options);
                    options.SignInScheme = Constants.B2CAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/openid");
                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        await AuthorizationHelper.ValidateB2CAppToken(context, RequireAccountNum);
                    };
                }, openIdConnectScheme: Constants.B2CAuthenticationScheme, cookieScheme: Constants.B2CCookieScheme)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi().AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(FischerLib.Extensions.Constants.B2CAuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddRequirements(new AzureB2CAuthorizationRequirement(RequireAccountNum)).Build();

                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            services.AddAuthorization(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(FischerLib.Extensions.Constants.B2CAuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddRequirements(new AzureB2CAuthorizationRequirement(RequireAccountNum)).Build();
                config.AddPolicy(Constants.PolicyExternalUsers, policy);
            });
        }
```

At the moment I'm using two controller which have authorize attributes restricted to the scheme. Accessing these controller redirects the user to the login.

But this is not the way which I want to use. After the code above is part of a library and I would like to avoid having to ad the controller in every project.

I know that there is a property `LoginPath` if I use a different scheme like cookies but I can't set this property in `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(...)`

Thank you very much!

Markus

Answer (score 0):

Please check this blog on [Building a Web Application that Supports both Azure AD and Azure AD B2C - MikaBerglund.com](https://mikaberglund.com/building-a-web-application-that-supports-both-azure-ad-and-azure-ad-b2c/)

> which works on how to enable  switching between Azure AD and Azure AD
> B2C just by changing the configuration i.e;`app settings.json` file
> where authority , clientId changes.

The controller actions need to route to selected auth schemes when required.
The way you have added controller seems to be the way.

You can raise a [***support request***](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/NewSupportRequestV3Blade/) for the same.

Reference:
[github ref](https://github.com/MikaBerglund/generic-open-id-connect-web-application)